# Printing Only a Few Entries From a Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

everyone!

I'm trying to write a python script dealing with a dictionary and a lot of values. The main code is easy, and I have that all done.

My only issue is that I only need to print and format couple of my dictionary entries. I have to print the first 4 and last four of an alphabetized 257-term dictionary.

This is the formatting I need to follow, but I have no issues getting the formatting correct.

```
             Afghanistan - South Asia      652230
                Akrotiri - Europe             123
                 Albania - Europe           28748
                 Algeria - Africa         2381740

               West Bank - Middle East       5860
                   Yemen - Middle East     527968
                  Zambia - Africa          752618
                Zimbabwe - Africa          390757
```

My only true problem is that (no matter what I try), I end up printing the entire dictionary with formatting.

I've looked everywhere and I just can't find anything that tells me how to only print the first 4 and last 4 entries of a dictionary. Things like list comprehensions seemed the most useful, but they print the whole dictionary. Can anyone help?

```
alphabetizedCountryDict = dict(sorted(countryDict.items()))
[print(f'{"%24s" % key} - {value[0]:13}{"%9s" % value[1]}') for key, value in alphabetizedCountryDict.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just sort the keys and use list slicing to filter for your desired keys, then call them in the dictionary.

```
sorted_keys = sorted(countryDict.keys())
target_keys = sorted_keys[:4] + sorted_keys[-4:]
for key in target_keys:
    print(format_function(key), '\t\t', countryDict[key])
```